# Using colors in aes() function in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to `ggplot2`. I am trying to understand how to use `ggplot`. I am reading Wickham's book and still trying to wrap my head around how to use `aes()` function. In a related thread, we discussed that we should try to avoid using variables inside `aes()` i.e. "Don't put constants inside `aes()` - only put mappings to actual data columns."

My objective is to observe the behavior of ggplots when we have color inside `aes()` for labeling (as described in Wickham's book) and also override the color to print the color.

I started with this:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mpg)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = "loess"), method = "loess", se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = "lm"), method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  labs(colour = "Method")
```

This nicely plots graphs and labels them. However, I am unhappy with the colors used. So, I experimented with using overriding colors again:

```
windows()
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = "loess"), method = "loess", se = FALSE, color = "magenta") +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = "lm"), method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "red") +  
  labs(colour ="Method")
```

I added color = "red" and we can see that `labs()` or `aes(color())` doesn't have any effect. Why does this happen? I'm curious. I'd appreciate thoughts.

Comment: I think this and the answer below may be working for the wrong reason. Shouldn't it be `method="loess"` not `color=...` cc:@user1470500

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you specify, the colour outside aes() gg_plot does not consider the color information being part of the data (and it overwrites previous information) , so there is no legend to display anymore.

If you want to specify your own colors and keep the colour information as "relevant data" and not "display information", you should add  a `scale_colour_manual()` command to specify the legend colours and leave the colour attribute in `aes`:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(aes(colour = "loess"), method = "loess", se = FALSE) +
    geom_smooth(aes(colour = "lm"), method = "lm", se = FALSE) +  
    labs(colour ="Method") + scale_colour_manual(values = c("loess" = "magenta", "lm" = "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to add your plot